# What is the best way to handle ~600 permanent redirects with absolute URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I have around 600 old URLs in this format:

```
http://www.example.com?articlename.random-numbers.html
```

which I want to redirect to the new format:

```
http://www.example.com?p=XXX (article number)
```

There is no correlation between the old and new URLs that I can use to create a common rule. I just have a list of the URL mapping. The old URLs will not exist any more, if that matters.

Can I use .htaccess or something else for this, or will I have to create my own solution in PHP?

Comment: Just FYI, removing the article name may hinder your SEO effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest handling this at the server (Apache) level using an .htaccess file.

Because the old URLs will not exist anymore, you should set these up as HTTP Status Code 301 redirects, as they indicate a permanent move: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

In your .htaccess file, for every article, create a line as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /?articlename.random-numbers.html http://www.yourdomain.com/?p=XXX
```

Your .htaccess file should sit at the root of your website.

Because there is no correlation between the old and new URLs that you can use to create a common rule, having a ~600 line .htaccess file is your best bet. (If there was some correlation, you could use Apache's mod_rewrite module to script this task.)

Comment: Ah, I thought redirecting a relative URL required an actual file. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Not only this rule is wrong this is also not the right way of solving this large 600+ redirects.

Comment: @anubhava How is this wrong? And what is the right way?

Comment: Because you cannot match query string in redirect rule. Right way is to use RewriteMap.

Comment: @anubhava Except I currently use this solution and it seems to work for me. I'll look into RewriteMap anyway.

Comment: If it works them you have deferent URL to match i.e.  `http://www.example.com/articlename.random-num`